# performance PHP select where vs left join

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-design, left-join

I work for multilangual book library cms. For DBs design i have two idea :

One :

```
id | title | desc | date | writer | publisher | lang | more more | ...
```

for result:

`result = SELECT blah1, blah2, foreign_key FROM foo WHERE key=bar AND lang = en`

Two: add another table for language :

```
id | book_id | lang
```

for result work with PHP `LEFT JOIN` methods.

which way is better and faster for big database ?!

NOTE:`I have 27 columns in my table and 4500 books.`

Comment: The second version with another table is more versatile.  You can easily add more languages, for isntance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, seconds way is faster ? or is only better way for add more lang?! If i separated `writer` and `publisher ` from first table and work with `left join` for result, is good way ?

Comment: Will the books in your database have multiple languages attached to each of them, or will each book only have one language?

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and descriptions of the sizes of the tables and how often you expect the query to run.

Comment: @George: each book only have one language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: i have 27 columns in my table and 4500 books.

Comment: @Perspolis . . . That is a pretty small database.  If you have the appropriate indexes, you won't have to worry about performance.

Comment: Be sure to have `INDEX(key, lang)` or `INDEX(lang, key)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: for this Q what's  the best appropriate indexes?!

Answer (score 0):

As each book only has one language you will just want a language_id column in the books table which references a languages table. The languages table will contain a list of all languages.

```
books:
id | title | ... | language_id

languages:
id | name | code
```

for example:

```
books:
id | title | language_id
1 | Othello | 1
2 | The Bible | 1
3 | Les Misérables | 2

languages:
id | name | code
1 | english | en
2 | french | fr
```

Then you can select books with a left join on books.language_id = languages.id

This way has the added benefit of being able to list all languages easily by selecting the contents of the languages table.